# Kendo UI Datasource Auto Increment ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Is there a way within the datasource that you can specify an Auto ID field within Kendo UI?

I.e. so when we are inserting rows programmatically the id is auto generated. The data is not coming from a remote source. The data is initially empty and rows created by users and stored locally to upload to a remote location at a later date. So we need the datasource to automatically generate an id.

Or will we have to do this programmatically ourselves, by creating a local storage sequence number and manually incrementing?

Comment: You want to add serial number in your kendoGrid?

Comment: I'm afraid kendo only have the `uid`, as you mentioned. A sequencial Id you will need to implement by yourself, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to auto-generate a sequence using the Kendo UI API. You'll have to do this using JavaScript.

Something like this:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
    if (e.model.isNew()) 
    {
        //set field
        var id = generateId();
        e.model.set("Id", id);
    }
}

function generateID() { 
    AutoID = 1; // Get the latest sequential ID for this sector. 
    if (localStorage.getItem('ID') !== "") {
        AutoID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('ID')) + 1; // Save the new ID 
        localStorage.setItem('ID', AutoID); 
    }
    return AutoID; 
}
```

Comment: I'll give you this. Here is my GenerateID function, incase it helps others.

Comment: function generateID()
{
    AutoID=1;
    
    // Get the latest sequential ID for this sector.
     if (localStorage.getItem('ID')!=="")
           AutoID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('ID')) + 1;
    
    // Save the new ID
    localStorage.setItem('ID', AutoID);   
    
     return AutoID;
}

Comment: @Shane  can we use that id as primary key of datasource schema? some thing like `schema: { model:  { id: generateId, fields: {} } } `?